# JSoup selecting radiobuttons

Tags: java, html, radio-button, jsoup

Good time of day ,

I have a question about using jsoup.
Working with one web site I met problem that before gathering information from list of products at first I need to select radio buttons and send required data about two parameters of products : "type" and "categories".

This web site if so:
http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/networking/products/eos/index.aspx#.WzYf4NIzY2z

Because if not to do it search will give list which have only one product from unknown category .
This: 
HP VCX V7205 Platform with DL 360 G6

I'm using such method at the begining.

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/networking/products/eos/index.aspx#.WzSdxdIzY2z")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .timeout(10 * 1000)
            .method(Method.POST)
            .data("type","2")
            .data("category","4")
            .followRedirects(true)
            .execute();
```

And then parse it.

```
Document document = response.parse();
```

But unfortunatly either I didn't understand how to send it correctly or I should choose another way of ,maybe , selecting correct list of products .As you may understand I try to choose second type and fouth category.
Could somebody advise how to do it ? Or advise example which could be useful for may case ?

Thank you for your attention

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to get the names of all the available products when choosing different combinations of the 'type' and 'category'? If so, you can find it in the following link - http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/data/xml/eos/eos.xml?a=0.6343206067226557